# Web2py DAL/built in select with JSON

Tags: python, web2py

I am wondering if the DAL supports select with JSON, or if there is a hack to make it able to select JSON fields. I can do the following:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM my_table WHERE my_json_colum::json->>'form_id' = '%s';" % (dummy_string)
my_count = db.executesql(query)
return my_count
```

However, the [docs](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#executesql) suggest this isn't reliabe:

> In this case, the return values are not parsed or transformed by the DAL, and the format depends on the specific database driver.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that suggested support for this. More specifically, when I run the above code it returns just the letter H. Is there a workaround (or better yet a legitimate way to do it that I missed) to get the DAL working with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DAL is able to save JSON data in individual fields, but it does not provide a mechanism for querying specific attributes of the JSON data, as that requires special functionality within the RDBMS itself, which is not supported by most databases.

Comment: Is there any work around for this, or do I just have to use raw SQL or make a sub query and then search the rows?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Does it (and its associated Python driver) support the syntax you are using? If so, `executesql` will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, executesql works for example with `select *...`, however it did not with   `select count(*)...`. In the end I just used `query = "select *..."
len(db.executesql(query))`,

Comment: `executesql` works for any query at all -- it simply sends the raw SQL via the Python driver and returns exactly what the Python driver returns. Most likely, you're simply not processing the returned data correctly.